# '!' does not exclude file in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

my `.gitignore` file:

```
.DS_Store
temp
!temp/script.txt
```

However when I do `git status` it doesn't display the `temp/` directory to indicate that the `script.txt` is not in staged. It only displays the `.gitignore` file:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
```

I'm just learning git. Any idea where i'm going wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `.gitignore` to ignore a file that is already versioned by Git.

Comment: @jszakmeister irrelevant here

Comment: @sehe You're probably right (which is why I didn't write it as an answer), but the double negative "it doesn't display the temp/ directory to indicate that the script.txt is not in the staged" makes it sound like it's part of the working tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `temp` with:

```
temp/*
```

This ignores all files in the directory. In most cases `temp`, `temp/` and `temp/*` all work the same because in the first two cases, the directory is ignore while in the third case, Git does not track empty directories. Thus, the directory itself will be ignored.

To illustrate this, this is essentially what happens when `temp/` has `temp1.txt temp2.txt temp3.txt`:

```
temp # anything with the name of "temp"; a directory, a symlink, a file.
temp/ # whole of temp dir
temp/* # temp/temp1.txt temp/temp2.txt temp/temp3.txt
```

Thus, the third case will work in your case.

The negation pattern must be placed after the pattern that covers it. In this case, `!temp/script.txt` must come after `temp/*`. Otherwise, it will not be applied.

So, your final .gitignore file should look like this:

```
.DS_Store
temp/*
!temp/script.txt
```

Comment: note you'll have to watch the order of inclusions/exclusions very carfully. Also, `temp` would ignore a file by the name `temp`, `temp/` only ignores (any) files in that directory

Comment: @sehe yep, i'll make sure to add that in. i excluded that to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Note directories are not versioned in git

Use a .gitignore of

```
temp/*
!temp/script.txt
```

Note that the order is *very important* (I had this wrong first, which is why I almost concluded it couldn't be done)